# Can't run paint method from main method

Tags: java, object

In the main method, I am trying to run this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    game.paintBlocks(g);
}
```

And getting a "cannot be resolved to variable" error for the "g" parameter.

Elsewhere I have this, which calls on another method in another class (paint(g)) to paint a grid of blocks:

```
public void paintBlocks(Graphics g)
{  
    for (int r = 0; r<7; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<5; c++)
        {
            block[r][c].paint(g);
        }
    }
```

Do I need to tell it that "g" is in another class?  I'm new to this and any help would be awesome!

Comment: Did you created a new Graphics object g on the main class,to use it in main function?

I assume that, you imported java.awt.Graphics or shortly, java.awt.*  .

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `paintBlocks`, `g` is a parameter that is being passed in to the method. In the case of `main`, `g` is referencing a variable that hasn't been created anywhere.

[`Graphics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) and [`Graphics2D`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) are abstract classes, and aren't generally intended to be instantiated except by Swing. What `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` give you is a context for drawing on a component (like a JPanel or a BufferedImage).

Based on your description you probably want to draw blocks on a Swing component of some kind. (Though it's a little unclear, that would be a normal kind of thing to do.) What you would normally want to do if you are drawing the blocks on a `JPanel`, for example, is to create a class that extends `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent()` method. One way you might do that:

```
public class BlocksPanel extends JPanel {
   // Normal class fields, etc.
   // ...

   // I would consider making this private, but this is your method from above:
   public void paintBlocks(Graphics g) {  
      for (int r = 0; r<7; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c<5; c++) {
            block[r][c].paint(g);
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      paintBlocks(Graphics g);
   }
}
```

There is another example that might help you on page 9 of [this document.](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~fdevries/java/java0708/voorbeeldcode/sudent.sol.man/jhtp7_SSM_12.pdf) The [Java Tutorials for the Java 2D API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html) may also help.

Comment: So is that like making an accessor method?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to paint to?  I'm assuming you probably want to paint to a window on the screen, in which case you won't be calling paint* yourself, you'll let the Swing framework call it at the appropriate times.  In this case, if `game` is a `JFrame`, then you just need to make it visible; or if `game` is some other type of component then you'll need to add it to a visible window.  This is the pattern I normally use when I'm teaching basic graphics in Java:

```
public class MyGame extends JPanel {
  public static void main() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("My Game");
    window.add(new MyGame());
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centers the window on the screen
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible();
  }
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(800, 600);
  }
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Do my drawing here
  }
}
```

If you want to paint to an off-screen image, then you'll need to create your own graphics context to pass to the paint* methods:

```
BufferedImage hello = new BufferedImage(game.getWidth(), game.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = hello.getGraphics();
game.paintBlocks( g );
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `g` is undefined in the main context because you havent declared/initialised it. If you look at your `paintBlocks(Graphics g)` method, `g` is passed as a parameter, however the scope of that variable(`g`) is within the braces(`{}`) of the method `paintBlocks(Graphics g)`.

If you have a class called `MyClass` that extends a Component, say `JPanel`, you can do something like this:

```
class MyClass extends JPanel
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         Graphics g = getGraphics(); //would return the graphics object for the JPanel
         game.paintBlocks(g);
     }
}
```

Its also good to note that the above method in some cases would be tagged as bad programming style. There is an alternative. You can make use of the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method provided by the component.

Your main would then look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   repaint(); //this repaints the component, calling the paintComponent method
}
```

Its also bad programming style to call `paintComponent(Graphics g)` yourself. You should allow your system to call that method and thats why you have the `repaint()` method. The system automatically invokes `paintComponent(Graphics g)` when you repaint.

From `paintComponent(Graphics g)` you can then do this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g); //repainting the panel,not necessary in some cases
    game.paintBlocks(g); //passing the graphics object used by the component
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: I think this is kind of beyond me unfortunately.  Thanks for the help though guys.

Comment: No it isin't, its just a better way of doing what you want to do.